# Writing multiple geometries to Interlis using FME

Tags: fme-form, oracle-spatial, interlis

I have to write Features with more than one geometry to interlis. In the Interlis model there is a class which has an optional second geometry as an attribute. Enabling the (Oracle-) Reader to read multiple geometries works. FME reads point-features with its polygons. Now, how do I write the point-geometry as primary geometry to interlis, and the polygons as "optional" geometry to the specified attribute?

Attached you will find the interlis-model, the class I need to write is "InfrastrukturKnoten" with its optional geometry "Detailgeometrie".

Problems so far:

- when switching to Geometry-Type "FME-XML" instead of "FME-BIN" I get Oracle read Errors on non-spatial tables
- when switching to "handle multiple spatial columns = yes" at the Oracle Spatial Reader, I also get Oracle ORA-01002: FETCH auf ungültigen oder geschlossenen Cursor Errors

[Interlis-Model](https://www.ag.ch/media/kanton_aargau/bvu/dokumente_2/umwelt__natur___landschaft/umweltschutzmassnahmen_1/siedlungsentwaesserung_1/Abwasserkataster_AG_V2_LV95_2019-04-12_IL23.zip)

Comment: Are you using the Interlis reader/writer? According to the documentation, this format is created by a third party and you can find more information on how it works here: http://www.ili2fme.ch/

Comment: Yes, but ili2fme doesn't supply any support. They direct to stackexchange and the FME Community for technical support. I wasn't able to find any information on that specific problem on both online resources.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to study the article [Writing to Database Tables that contain Multiple Geometry Columns](https://community.safe.com/s/article/writing-to-tables-that-contain-multiple-geometry-c).

Comment: thanks, I already saw this article, but it shows how to write into databases, not to Interlis.
As I already am reading those classes with multiple geometries correctly, I see the difficulty in writing them to Interlis. (second geometry redirected into a specific attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, it's best to disable "multiple spatial column support" at the reader.
I now read the additional geometries as separate feature class and extract the geometry (using Geometryextractor) into an attribute an join these to the original class. Interlis Writer picked up the geometries (in attribute) and wrote them to the specified attribute as planned.